# ASP.NET - I am generating an .XLS file with a DLL, how do I grant permissions for writing to file? (IIS 7)

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, vb.net, iis

I'm generating an .XLS file with a DLL (Excel Library http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/)

I've added this DLL as a reference to my project.

The code to save the .XLS to disk is running, but it's encountering a permissions issue.

I've attempted to set full access for IUSRS, Network Service, and Everyone just to see if I could get it working, and none of these seems to make a difference.

Here's where I'm trying to write the file:

```
c:/temp/test1.xls
```

Here's the error:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +54
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +2103
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +138
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +89
   System.IO.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +58
   ExcelLibrary.Office.CompoundDocumentFormat.CompoundDocument.Create(String file) +88
   ExcelLibrary.Office.Excel.Workbook.Save(String file) +73
   CHC_Reports.LitAnalysis.CreateSpreadSheet_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\brian\Desktop\Enterprise Manager\CHC_Reports\LitAnalysis.aspx.vb:19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +11041511
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +11041050
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +91
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +240
   ASP.litanalysis_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +52
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +599
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171
```

Any idea what I need to do to diagnose the permissions issue and allow the file creation?

Thanks.

Comment: is the assembly running from a network share? or perhaps the sites running in medium trust?

Comment: Can you store the excel in memory and stream it back to the browser. Or do have to save the file to disk?

Comment: @Tried taht ggonsalv, but the library only allows saving to a path unfortunately. @Ori, it's running locally on II7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Nelson was on the right track for 90% of people that run into this error... and I believe that tgolisch was on the right track for about 8% of the remaining.

However, the application pool that was serving up my application apparently did not have specific rights to write to the folders in question. Therefore, I switched the application pool being used to serve up the application to run under the context: Local System.

When I deploy the application, I will need to determine which identity the application pool is running under and verify that it has access to the appropriate folders.

Comment: In that case, I'm surprised giving "Everyone" permissions didn't work.  Maybe IUSR* and IWAM* are not part of "Everyone".  Anyway, you can create a simple ASP.NET page to show Environment.UserName, which I think will give you the right account.  If you're still having trouble, you can run Process Monitor from Sysinternals/Microsoft and see exactly which account is accessing the file.  It's also not recommended to use Local System since you are giving extra, unneeded permissions and can compromise security.

Answer (score 2):

I think this doesn't have to do with the file security, but rather .NET code access security.  You can install the .NET SDK which will add something like ".NET 2.0 Configuration" in Administrative Tools where you can configure it, or use the caspol command line utility.  Also, check this article specifically for ASP.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998326.aspx

**Edit:**  Now that I look a bit more, notice *CodeAccessSecurity*Engine.  It definitely seems to be what I thought.  You give or deny specific permissions to .NET applications based on URI, strong name, etc.  Those permissions include access to files, the registry, etc.

Comment: Note: the .NET SDK and caspol utility allow you to view and add custom rules.  You can use the existing ones without any of these tools by editing the web.config.  Check out the article.

Comment: "you can use the existing ones" = "you can use the existing rules such as Full Trust, Medium Trust".  In .NET 1.1, the configuration UI utility was included with the .NET runtime installation, so you'll usually see it in Administrative Tools.  Since .NET 2.0, you have to install it separately.  It's included in the .NET 2+ SDK, but the SDK also installs a bunch of other things.  You may be able to get it individually somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

When writing a file to the HDD from IIS, you need to set "write" permissions on the folder (for your example, c:\temp).  This is because some IO processes delete, then recreate a file (instead of just updating), and the permissions are destroyed when the file is deleted.
Usually, you need to grant read/write to IUSR*, IWAM* and ASPNET.